# Dual (additional) battery E-bike solution

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, relay, components, lithium-ion

What would be better solution when attemptng to install additional battery on E-bike:

1. Parallel connection and increasing total Ah (batteries are from different manufacturers).
2. Idividual usage of each battery and switching after main battery is certain % auto or manually.

Also with second option, what are some good microcontollers or relay modules I can purchase?

As I did some research it seems to me that voltage sensitive relays (VSR) are not applicable in this case.

```
Bike model: OIO City Bike
Main battery: 36V, 10.4 Ah, Li-ION, downtube integrated, waterproof.
Motor: 350 Watt, brushless, maintenance-free
Charger: DC Out 42V 2A
```

[image: parallel]
[image: switch]
[image: citybike]

Comment: That's an AC rated switch. It's not good for switching DC.

Comment: You show a picture of a wimpy switch that can **by far** not handle the currents that are needed in an E-bike. You have to learn a lot more about electronics before you can safely do what you propose in your question. Realize that if you get things wrong then your battery might be damaged or catch fire. With these things you **must** know what you're doing. You cannot acquire all the knowledge you need by asking a couple of questions here. Instead, look on sites with similar E-bike modifications and learn how others have done this with success.

Comment: Picture is just for reference, of course this requires DC switch. It's not that car or marine switches are not reliable, it's also about ergonomics.

Comment: 350W motor is near 10A at rated power and 100A start current full acceleration and connecting battery current is delta V/ (ESR1+ESR2) may be more if voltage is different by 20%

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Right, but it's approximately startup current, besides, computer hadles gradual acceleration. With that said, is DC36V 40A rated car relay gonna be in margin of safety in terms of FoS?

Comment: Depends on the conditions under which it is used. Switch between batteries cause surge from voltage difference at low ESR and cutoff while motor is running sustains the current to burn contacts until dissipated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parallel connection and increasing total Ah (batteries are from different manufacturers).

That's a **really bad** thing to do. You should never connect batteries / battery packs in parallel unless you **REALLY** know what you're doing and then the batteries should be of the same model and preferably of similar age and wear level.

If you ignore this advice and do it anyway then you risk that your batteries will be damaged and/or will start smoking and/or will catch fire. So just **don't**.

> Idividual usage of each battery and switching after main battery is certain % auto or manually.

Manual switching should be OK, make sure that at any time only **one** + pole of the battery is connected to the bike's electronics. Put fuses in series so that if currents become too high the fuse blows.

Automatic switching will complicate things, if you have to ask how to do this then you probably lack the experience to do this. Then used a ready-made solution: you buy some suitable device, connect the batteries according to the manual and that's it. If that doesn't exist or you cannot find it: use manual switching.

> Also with second option, what are some good microcontollers or relay modules I can purchase?

That is a "shopping question" and therefore off topic on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By purchase I mean examples applicable in this case. Preferrably all-in-one solutions. Relays I've found so far were either for cars or factory machines. Maybe, some Arduino modules?..

Comment: Hmm, the fact that you think that a "relay for a car" would not be suitable for your project tells me you lack the experience to build something yourself. The fact that a relay is designed for car applications doesn't mean it cannot be used. Some car relays support high currents and are usable in moving vehicles (shaking etc), so I'd say a car relay is **very** suitable. Experienced designers will look at the datasheet and then decide if a component is suitable. Regarding microcontrollers: an experienced engineer can use almost **ANY** microcontroller that exists for this type of project.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that most e-bike battery packs have a communication interface (CAN, UART) to the motor and display. You also have to switch these signals with the power connection. Parallel usage will never work because the components are not designed for that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well the simplest solution is just manual connector switching, but this is terrible waterproof decision. I'm no electrical engineer nor a student in this field. My highest knowledge of EE is high school. Any good literature you suggest for E-bike enthusiasts?

Comment: @A.R.C. But displays are mostly universal, right? I mean they can properly show different rated Ah batteries discharge level based on voltage at the moment?

Comment: I work for a company which develops a lot of E-Bike batteries and we have different protocols for all displays. The batteries are designed to work with multiple motor and display producers but this has to be configured in the production line and can not be done by the end customer.